# Unable to make ajax requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am running a nodejs server to run my website, and I want the backend server to make a call to an api on an external server.  I tried the following, basic and straightforward method:

```
router.post('/calculate', function (req, res) {

var data = /*some json object*/

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "some.server/pricing");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {


    if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        var str = xmlhttp.responseText.toString().trim()
        dd = JSON.parse(str);
        res.send(dd);
        //res.end();

    }


};

});
```

When I run this I get:

```
 _http_outgoing.js:346
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

The issue seems to be in res.send(dd);

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, it seems like xmlhttp.onreadystatechange happens twice with status 200, and res.send is called twice. I created a temporary hack to fix this using a boolean flag, what is the rpoper nodejs way to fix this?

What is the most straightforward way of making such a call in nodejs? I want this done on the server side. I am not using any libraries like express. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use `XMLRequest`. It's an ancient client-side design that is pretty horrible for server-side requests (thus the problem you had) that is even being replaced in the browser. Either use `http.request()` or easier, use the `request` module on npm which are natively designed for node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Easy do it with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package

```
var request = require('request');
request({
    url: 'some.server/pricing',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    form: data
}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) res.send(err)
    else res.send(body)
});
```

Comment: Much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more investigation, I found out that res.send was being called twice. The reason this was happening was because the xmlhttp object changes its state several times:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

I fixed the code to:

```
 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
```

Now everything works properly.